# Distribution of $r$ balls into $n$ cells leaving none of the cells empty.

Tags: probability

There are $n$ distinguishable cells and $r$ distinguishable balls. Let $A(r,n)$ be the number of distributions leaving none of the cells empty. Show by combinatorial argument that

$A(r, n+1) = \sum_{k=1}^r rC_k \times A(r-k, n)$

**Note**: This is a question from "An Introduction To Probability: Theory and its Applications" by William Feller. I have tried it, but there seems to be something wrong with my counting. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $n+1$ cells, and want to put balls in them, so that each cell will have at least one ball.

First look at the $(n+1)$-th cell. We can **imagine** putting any number $k$ of balls in this cell, where $1\le k\le r$.

For any $k$, the $k$ balls that will go into Cell $n+1$ can be chosen in $\binom{r}{k}$ ways. By definition, the remaining $n$ cells can be legally filled using the remaining $r-k$ balls in $A(r-k,n)$ ways, for  total of $\binom{r}{k}A(r-k,n)$ ways.

Now add up, $k=1$ to $r$.  That gives the recurrence of the post.

Note that for large $k$, the term $A(r-k,n)$ will be equal to $0$.

Comment: Your solutions seems sound and valid. Help me with my reasoning. To fill n+1 cells n+1 balls can be selected in $rC_(n+1)$ ways. Since the balls are distinguishable they can be further arranged in (n+1)! ways. For the remaining r-n-1 balls can be filled in (n+1)^(r-n-1)ways. Is this correct? Because going by this method the results dont add up.

Comment: The sort of approach you are suggesting runs into troubles with distinguishable balls. You are contemplating doing the problem in stages, first meet the at least one condition, then do the rest. The problem is "multiple" counting. Suppose in your first stage we put Ball $a$ in Cell $7$, and in the second stage we put Ball $b$ in Cell $7$. That's the same result as in first stage we put Ball $b$ in Cell $7$, and in the second stage we put Ball $a$ in Cell $7$. The multiple counting would be OK if we knew by what *factor* we multiple count. (Cont.)

Comment: However, if Cell $7$ ends up with $3$ balls, we have a different multiple-counting ratio than if it ends up with $2$ balls, or $5$, or $1$. For any distribution of numbers of balls in the cells, we have a different adjustment process. Except with very small numbers, things get out of control. The alternate approach to the problem involves Inclusion/Exclusion. We count the ways to fill without restriction (easy) and then remove the bad ones, where one or more cells are empty. We end up working with Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: You are welcome. The Inclusion/Exclusion argument works nicely. For general theory, a little hard to read, you may want to look at Wikipedia, The Twelvefold Way.