# what's the probability of putting r balls into n cells with no cells empty?

Tags: probability

I'm reading the book `An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications` by William Feller and trying to solve the problems after chapters. I can figure out the probability can be rewritten as

$$A(r, n+1) = \sum_{k=1}^{r} {r \choose k}A(r-k, n)$$

which explained clearly by this question ([Distribution of $r$ balls into $n$ cells leaving none of the cells empty.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923558/distribution-of-r-balls-into-n-cells-leaving-none-of-the-cells-empty))

But, I cannot make it out that $$A(r, n+1)$$ has the final result as

$$A(r, n) = \sum_{v=0}^{n} (-1)^v{n \choose v}(n-v)^r$$

How does it get there? Any hints will be really appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can try induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just [inclusion exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement).

In this case $A(r,n)$ seems to be the number of ways to put $r$ balls in $n$ boxes so none is empty.

Clearly The first summad gives us all of the possible asignments ($\binom{n}{0}n^r=n^r$).

The next term is $-1\binom{n}{1}(n-1)^r$. This is equal to all of the permutations in which the first box is empty, plus the number of assignments in which the second box is empty and so on.